# Why is my viewModel updated in HTML but not in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a function that moves a line item up one line at a time. For simplicity, I'm showing a small part of the code. My observable's display as expected in HTML using $root.cRecordID, but in my code, they are undefined. It's confusing and frustrating. Can anyone shed some light?

```
listOrderUp: function (lid) {
    // get RecordID of selected item
    //viewModel.loadItemByID(lid);
    console.log(lid);

    OData.read(_serviceURL + "/nsLineItems(" + lid + ")?", function (response) {
        viewModel.cRecordID(response.RecordID);
        viewModel.cMenuID(response.MenuID);
        viewModel.cEntreeID(response.EntreeID);
        viewModel.cCategoryID(response.CategoryID);
        viewModel.cListOrder(response.ListOrder);
    });

    console.log(viewModel.cRecordID());

    // selected item - decrease ListOrder by 1
    var putdataCurrent = {
        RecordID: viewModel.cRecordID(),
        MenuID: viewModel.cMenuID(),
        CategoryID: viewModel.cCategoryID(),
        EntreeID: viewModel.cEntreeID(),
        ListOrder: viewModel.cListOrder() - 1
    };

    console.log(putdataCurrent);

    var _requestCurrent = {
        requestUri: _serviceURL + "/nsLineItems(" + viewModel.cListOrder() + ")",
        method: "MERGE",
        data: putdataCurrent
    };

    OData.request(_requestCurrent, function (data) {
    });
}
```

Here's console results:
[image]

Here's my html test code:

This displays the expected result, but I need the results in my code so I can save the data to the server. How can it be undefined in the code(javascript file) but it displays correctly in html? 
Thanks, Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I guess `OData.read(.....)` is an asynchronous call to a server? If so, I believe that your code which sets the value in `var putDataCurrent` is being executed before the call to the server has returned. If you put a couple of breakpoints where you set the results of the call to the observables and where you set the `putDataCurrent` and check which one gets hit first. If that's the problem you could move your code that within the 'success' callback of `OData.read` or potentially you could use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

I got the results I wanted by embedding the REST code inside the OData request:

```
listOrderUp: function (lid) {
    OData.read(_serviceURL + "/nsLineItems(" + lid + ")?", function (response) {
        viewModel.cRecordID(response.RecordID);
        viewModel.cMenuID(response.MenuID);
        viewModel.cEntreeID(response.EntreeID);
        viewModel.cCategoryID(response.CategoryID);
        viewModel.cListOrder(response.ListOrder);

        // selected item - decrease ListOrder by 1
        var putdataCurrent = {
            RecordID: viewModel.cRecordID(),
            MenuID: viewModel.cMenuID(),
            CategoryID: viewModel.cCategoryID(),
            EntreeID: viewModel.cEntreeID(),
            ListOrder: viewModel.cListOrder() - 1
        };

        console.log(putdataCurrent);

        var _requestCurrent = {
            requestUri: _serviceURL + "/nsLineItems(" + lid + ")",
            method: "MERGE",
            data: putdataCurrent
        };

        OData.request(_requestCurrent, function (data) {
        });
    });
    console.log(viewModel.cRecordID());
}
```